# Parse a site with DDoS guard

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, selenium-chromedriver, ssl-certificate, undetected-chromedriver

I have read quantities of info about using selenium and chromedriver. Nothing helped.

Then I tried undetected_chromedriver:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
url = "<url>"

driver = uc.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

driver.quit()
```

However, there's such a mistake:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)>
```

Guides in the net to avoid this mistake didn't help.

Maybe there's just a method to make the code wait 5 secs until the browser checking in process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,
I used Grap methods instead of requests.
Now it works. I think there's bypass method.

Grap documentation: https://grab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score -2):

So you will need to install a library called beautifulsoup4 and requests.

`pip install beautifulsoup4`

`pip install requests`

After that, try this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
html = requests.get("your url here").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
#use this to try to find elements:
#find_text = soup.find('pre', {'class': 'brush: python; title: ; notranslate'}).get_text()
```

Here is the beautifulsoup's documentation: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Well, the problem occurs when I do the get request. That's the topic of the question. Get request of the page returns the DDoS guard page.

Comment: I hope this one helps: https://solveforums.msomimaktaba.com/threads/solved-how-to-parse-site-that-is-protected-by-ddos-guard.610111/

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not. It is not solved as well.